WebSocket Angular
Al compilar mi proyecto Angular, la variable de WebSocket en el archivo environment.ts permanece fijada a una IP específica. Incluso después de editarla, sigue utilizando la IP anterior. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Muestra el código, idealmente un [mcve].

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
